# Spring JMS Use Point-to-point and Topic in the same application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We are currently introducing ActiveMQ into our existing application which was running on a different Queueing system. Spring JMS is used to make use of the existing integration within the Spring framework.

Most of our applications use point-to-point (queue) communication, with the exception of one. It needs to be able to listen to the topic created by another producing application while publishing to multiple queues at the same time.

This means that application needs to support both Topics and Queues. However, when setting the global property

```
jms:
    pub-sub-domain: true
```

the setting is global and all queue subscribers are immediately subscribing to topics, which we can see in the ActiveMQ web interface.

**Is there a way to configure the application to support both topics and queues at the same time?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boot property is used to configure the default container factory used by `@JmsListener` methods, as well as to configure the `JmsTemplate`.

Simply override Boot's default container factory...

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

and then add a second one

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsTopicListenerContainerFactory(
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true); << override the boot property
    return factory;
}
```

Then refer to the alternate factory in the `@JmsListener` for the topic.

Alternatively, if you don't have listeners for both types, set the property to `true`, but override Boot's `JmsTemplate` configuration.

Comment: It's important to have factory.setPubSubDomain(true) be called after configurer.configure(...). In other case Spring Boot will override this setting based on your application.yml (spring.jms.pubSubDomain=false by default if not specified)